# How to reorder nodes (change depth) in a scatterplot for an animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have a bunch of points in a scatterplot which overlap.  I am using `FuncAnimation` to create an animation.  In successive frames I would like to change which appear in front of the others.

As a simple MCVE, consider the code below in which each frame makes a different set of points be red.  However, these red points are often largely obscured by other points.  I would like to make these red points come to the front.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random

def update(time, plotted_points, N):
    #in here I would like to update the order that the points are plotted in.  I would like the red points to come to the front.
    color_change_indices = set(random.choices(range(N), k=1000))
    colors = ['red' if n in color_change_indices else 'gray' for n in range(N)]
    plotted_points.set_color(colors)
    return plotted_points


def animate(N):
    x = [random.random() for val in range(N)]
    y = [random.random() for val in range(N)]

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plotted_points = ax.scatter(x, y, color='gray')

    fargs = (plotted_points, N)

    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames = range(100), fargs = fargs)
    plt.show()


animate(10000)
```

I can change their color.  I can move their coordinates.  However, so far I cannot modify their relative depth.

So far the best idea I have is that perhaps I should delete the plotted points and then replot them.  But I don't have a deep understanding of matplotlib, and my attempts to delete them have failed so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a second `scatter` plot, red coloured and with a higher `zorder`, and update its points:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random
plt.ion()


def update(time, red_plotted_points, points, N):
    indexes = set([random.choice(range(N)) for i in range(int(N/2))])  # for instance!
    new_points = [points[i] for i in indexes]
    red_plotted_points.set_offsets(new_points)


def animate(N):
    x = [random.random() for val in range(N)]
    y = [random.random() for val in range(N)]
    points = [[x[i], y[i]]for i in range(N)]

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plotted_points = ax.scatter(x, y, color='gray', zorder=1)
    red_plotted_points = ax.scatter([], [], color='red', zorder=2)  # starts empty

    fargs = (red_plotted_points, points, N)

    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=range(100), fargs=fargs,
                        interval=200, repeat=True)

    ani._start()
    fig.show()
    return fig, ani


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig, ani = animate(100)
```

(python 2.7.14, matplotlib 2.1.1)

> Edit: Updated to also run on Python 3.6.3, matpotlib 2.1.0

I'm not sure why, but it seems that if a reference is not kept to the `FuncAnimation` it does not work on Python 3.6. Thanks to Joel (comments) for noticing.

Comment: Sorry, but when I run this in Python 3.6 [after replacing `N/2` by `int(N/2)`] I don't seem to get any output.

Comment: I don't understand why, but if you add `return fig, ani` at the end of `animate` function and make `fig, ani = animate(100)` it animates in Python 3.6.3, matpotlib 2.1.0. Maybe it has to do with the animation permanence in memory, but I really don't know (returning 1 or `None` does not work, returning something that causes a `NameError` strangely enables the animation).

Comment: Also, if you are using an Ipython console, I don't know if inline graphs allow animation. I thought `plt.ion()` would take care of it, but you might have to call `%matplotlib` on the Ipython console to change the backend to default (Qt5Agg in my case).

Answer (score 0):

In order to bring red points in front, you need to sort the data where red points come last. In a following code, instead of sorting the points by their color, it shuffles the data and draws last 1000 points with red, at each time update is called.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random

import numpy as np # np.random.shuffle

def update(time, plotted_points):
    # Extract data and colors
    data = plotted_points.get_offsets()
    colors = plotted_points.get_facecolor()

    # shuffle the data [N, 2] along the first axis
    np.random.shuffle(data)

    # Set shuffled data and reset colors
    plotted_points.set_offsets(data)
    plotted_points.set_color(colors)

    return plotted_points

def animate(N):
    x = [random.random() for val in range(N)]
    y = [random.random() for val in range(N)]

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    # Need to define colors at first.
    colors = ['red' if idx < 1000 else 'gray' for idx in range(N)]
    colors.reverse()
    plotted_points = ax.scatter(x, y, color=colors)

    fargs = (plotted_points,)

    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames = range(100), fargs = fargs)
    plt.show()


animate(10000)
```